concatenating list of mp4 getting Error parsing the packet header and other errors
I have a number of mp4s that were in some cases converted to mp4 from other formats using ffmpeg.
Now I want to concatenate these files into one.
I decided to use the concat list method
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0  -i list.txt -c copy out.mp4

which ended up giving me the
Non-monotonous DTS in output stream previous current changing to This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file

error.
So then I tried
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -segment_time_metadata 1 -i list.txt -vf select=concatdec_select -af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1 out.mp4

and I got a bunch of errors
aist#0:1/opus @ 0x12f6109b0] [dec:opus @ 0x12f66f4f0] Error submitting packet to decoder: Invalid data found when processing input
[opus @ 0x12f6702a0] Error parsing the packet header.

And the video is choppy, bits cut off, and the audio sounds like cheerios being eaten.
I'm not an expert in this area, obviously so I am at a loss to fix it. I would expect that there was a setting to say - take the formatting of the first video in this set and apply it to all the others, convert audio to audio etc. But don't cut off the time.
On edit - trying to use ffprobe to diagnose issues.
One of the files that gets the error:
 Error submitting packet to decoder: Invalid data found when processing input
[opus @ 0x12576fad0] Error parsing the packet header.

is 04.mp4, so I tried
ffprobe 4.mp4 and it told me
    ffprobe version 7.0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/7.0.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5026 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4890 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

And the first file is 0.mp4, which ffprobe tells me is
  ffprobe version 7.0.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2024 the FFmpeg developers
      built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
      configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/7.0.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
      libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
      libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
      libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
      libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
      libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
      libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
      libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
      libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '0.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
      Duration: 00:00:13.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1901 kb/s
      Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x710 [SAR 1:1 DAR 128:71], 1411 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k tbn (default)
          Metadata:
            handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
            vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: opus (Opus / 0x7375704F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
          Metadata:
            handler_name    : SoundHandler
            vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

but it looks the same to me

One is Opus audio 48000Hz. The other AAC 44100Hz. Also, if the original encoding parameters of the video streams differed, you are going to get issues when not re-encoding. One of yours is Main profile, the other is High. Different resolutions as well. Your two files are certainly not "the same".

OK thanks, that's why I mentioned that I am not an expert in this area, which is why was hoping to hear what I should do to sync these up.

You need to re-encode the original videos. Scaling to the same resolution and using the same parameters should enable you to concatenate (no further re-encoding required) without issues.
